# Ubuntu 16.10. external ntfs-3g harddrive gets ejected randomly during the night

Tags: mount, power-management, ntfs, external-hdd, ntfs-3g

⇒  uname -a
    Linux nortrom 4.8.0-41-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:27:17 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Today I woke up to my external harddrive of my ubuntu homeserver being turned off, despite active downloads that should have used the HDD.

It is connected via USB3.0 and mounted with ntfs-3g.

this is my fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=1668e1da-1b39-44c2-b24d-437fbbbbb49a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=510a4eaa-b436-4f4d-9fd5-e3ea22781716 none            swap    sw              0       0

/dev/sdb1       /mnt/media      ntfs-3g         uid=radon,gid=radon,utf8,noatime        0       0
```

Here is a snippet of the syslog I think contains relevant information:

```
... (everything looks uneventful and working fine)
Mar 18 03:40:59 nortrom kernel: [34613.632912] perf: interrupt took too long (4919 > 4913), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 40500
Mar 18 04:12:33 nortrom kernel: [36507.964516] usb 2-1: Disable of device-
initiated U1 failed.
Mar 18 04:12:33 nortrom kernel: [36507.967914] usb 2-1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
Mar 18 04:12:33 nortrom kernel: [36508.087759] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Mar 18 04:17:01 nortrom CRON[32092]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar 18 04:17:16 nortrom kernel: [36790.577485] usb 2-1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
Mar 18 04:17:21 nortrom kernel: [36795.833445] usb 2-1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
Mar 18 04:17:21 nortrom kernel: [36795.953637] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Mar 18 05:16:10 nortrom kernel: [40326.892005] usb 2-1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
Mar 18 05:16:16 nortrom kernel: [40332.108814] usb 2-1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
Mar 18 05:16:16 nortrom kernel: [40332.229263] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Mar 18 05:16:21 nortrom kernel: [40337.588134] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Mar 18 05:16:21 nortrom kernel: [40337.694801] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Mar 18 05:16:27 nortrom kernel: [40342.966281] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Mar 18 05:16:27 nortrom kernel: [40343.281359] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Mar 18 05:16:32 nortrom kernel: [40348.499517] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Mar 18 05:16:32 nortrom kernel: [40348.607185] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Mar 18 05:16:38 nortrom kernel: [40353.978425] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Mar 18 05:16:38 nortrom kernel: [40354.294122] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Mar 18 05:16:43 nortrom kernel: [40359.511950] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Mar 18 05:16:43 nortrom kernel: [40359.619580] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Mar 18 05:16:49 nortrom kernel: [40364.991096] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Mar 18 05:16:49 nortrom kernel: [40365.306454] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Mar 18 05:16:54 nortrom kernel: [40370.524342] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Mar 18 05:16:54 nortrom kernel: [40370.632007] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Mar 18 05:17:00 nortrom kernel: [40376.003500] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Mar 18 05:17:00 nortrom kernel: [40376.166739] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
Mar 18 05:17:00 nortrom kernel: [40376.182225] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Mar 18 05:17:00 nortrom kernel: [40376.182230] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 5f 4e e0 00 00 10 00
Mar 18 05:17:00 nortrom kernel: [40376.182233] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6246112
Mar 18 05:17:00 nortrom kernel: [40376.208989] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Mar 18 05:17:00 nortrom kernel: [40376.208995] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 16 de 1d 00 00 00 08 00
Mar 18 05:17:00 nortrom kernel: [40376.208997] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 383655168
Mar 18 05:17:00 nortrom kernel: [40376.209063] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 47956640, lost async page write
Mar 18 05:17:00 nortrom kernel: [40376.659280] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Mar 18 05:17:00 nortrom kernel: [40376.659348] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Mar 18 05:17:00 nortrom systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems.
Mar 18 05:17:00 nortrom systemd[1]: Unmounting /mnt/media...
Mar 18 05:17:00 nortrom umount[851]: umount: /mnt/media: target is busy
Mar 18 05:17:00 nortrom umount[851]:         (In some cases useful info about processes that
Mar 18 05:17:00 nortrom umount[851]:          use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
Mar 18 05:17:00 nortrom systemd[1]: mnt-media.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Mar 18 05:17:00 nortrom systemd[1]: Failed unmounting /mnt/media.
Mar 18 05:17:00 nortrom systemd[1]: mnt-media.mount: Unit is bound to inactive unit dev-sdb1.device. Stopping, too.
.... (gets repeated around 20 more times)
Mar 18 05:17:01 nortrom systemd[1]: Unmounting /mnt/media...
Mar 18 05:17:01 nortrom umount[867]: umount: /mnt/media: target is busy
Mar 18 05:17:01 nortrom umount[867]:         (In some cases useful info about processes that
Mar 18 05:17:01 nortrom umount[867]:          use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
Mar 18 05:17:01 nortrom systemd[1]: mnt-media.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Mar 18 05:17:01 nortrom systemd[1]: Failed unmounting /mnt/media.
Mar 18 05:17:01 nortrom systemd[1]: mnt-media.mount: Unit is bound to inactive unit dev-sdb1.device, but not stopping since we tried this too often recently.
Mar 18 05:17:01 nortrom kernel: [40377.066633] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Mar 18 05:17:01 nortrom CRON[869]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar 18 05:17:04 nortrom kernel: [40380.909463] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 49611520, async page read
Mar 18 05:17:05 nortrom ntfs-3g[469]: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Mar 18 05:17:05 nortrom ntfs-3g[469]: ntfs_attr_pread error reading '/Downloads/----some-file----.part17.rar.part' at offset 0: 65536 <> -1: In$Mar 18 05:17:05 nortrom ntfs-3g[469]: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Mar 18 05:17:05 nortrom ntfs-3g[469]: ntfs_attr_pread error reading '/Downloads/----some-file----.part17.rar.part' at offset 0: 4096 <> -1: Inp$Mar 18 05:17:05 nortrom kernel: [40380.974103] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 49611520, async page read
Mar 18 05:17:06 nortrom kernel: [40382.405707] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Mar 18 05:17:06 nortrom kernel: [40382.512776] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Mar 18 05:17:10 nortrom ntfs-3g[469]: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Mar 18 05:17:10 nortrom ntfs-3g[469]: Reading $BITMAP failed: Input/output error
Mar 18 05:17:10 nortrom ntfs-3g[469]: Failed to allocate clusters: Input/output error
Mar 18 05:17:10 nortrom ntfs-3g[469]: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Mar 18 05:17:10 nortrom ntfs-3g[469]: Reading $BITMAP failed: Input/output error
Mar 18 05:17:10 nortrom ntfs-3g[469]: Failed to allocate clusters: Input/output error
Mar 18 05:17:10 nortrom ntfs-3g[469]: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Mar 18 05:17:10 nortrom ntfs-3g[469]: Failed to read $MFT bitmap: Input/output error
Mar 18 05:17:10 nortrom kernel: [40386.786399] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 786431, async page read
```

rest is extremely high number of entries spammed, that ntfs_read failed.

After this incident, I could not re-mount the drive as it didn't appear in /dev/ anymore. Even reconnecting the usb-cable didn't help. The device's hdd-LED was turned off. I had to reboot the machine to get it working again.

Question is, what caused this? How can I avoid it in the future? Do you need any additional information?